# How assign value to a JSON string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I get this JSON object from my web service

```
0:  {
Username: "John"
Password: "12345"
Position: "Admin"
Job: "Developer"
ResourceJobId: 1
}
```

When I try to assign a value, for example, to Username JSON string, I get a semantic error:

```
id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                   error:&error];
            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
                NSString *usernameString = @"";
//this line of code gives me an error: Expression is not assignable               
[dictionary objectForKey:@"Username"] = usernameString   ;
```

I know how get the JSON object with NSJSONSerialization class, but my target is how assign the value @"" to the JSON object.
So how can I assign the value @"" to the Username JSON string?

Comment: use [dictionary setValue@"" forKey@""]

Comment: I don't see an "array" anywhere, so this is not your complete code. Show us your _complete_ code. I also don't know what you mean by "semantic error". Do you mean an error message by the compiler? What error message? Best to copy and paste.

Comment: in that way, I get this error [__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are trying to fetched `dictionary` from `array`. it is not mutable dictionary so you need to created `NSMutableDictionary` while fetching data from `Array`. following code will help you to change `username`.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in array)
{
   NSMutableDictionary* dictTemp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];

   [dictTemp setObject:usernameString forKey@"Username"];

   [_arrayList replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dictTemp];
}
```

Comment: @junko76, let me know you want some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Well your assignment operation is written wrong, it should be indeed like this:

- If you need to get value from dictionary

  ```
  usernameString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Username"];
  ```
- If you want to set a value to your dictionary, first of all your dictionary should be `NSMutableDictionary`

  ```
  [dictionary setObject:usernameString forKey:@"Username"];
  ```

Comment: I want to set a value to my dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError *error;
        id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                   error:&error];

        if(!error && [obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            NSArray *array = (NSArray *)obj;
            Booking *booking = nil;
            for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in array) {
               NSString *usernameString = @"";
//this line of code gives me an error: Expression is not assignable               
[dictionary objectForKey:@"Username"] = usernameString;
```

Yes, is a compiler error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a mutabledictionary inorder to change the value. Try this

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
   NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
   NSString *usernameString = @"";     
   [mutableDictionary setValue:@"" forKey:usernameString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the answers are correct, I want to add that you do not have to do this your own. `NSJSONSerialization` already has a solution for that. Simply pass as options one of these:

```
NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves = (1UL << 1),
```

when reading the JSON.

Comment: I wanted to add one vote at all, but I'm new on satckoverflow, so I'm not allowed to do it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I'm not here for rep, but to help. You're welcome.